# How old was Rae before her reincarnation (and how old is Claire)?

Tags: im-in-love-with-the-villainess

In *I'm in Love With the Villainess*, Rae Taylor was once an overworked office worker named Rei Oohashi before being reincarnated in the world of *Revolution*. I realised recently that, while Rae and Claire are physically the same age, Rae must actually be a few years older - at the very least, Rae can't be younger than 18, and Claire can't be older than 18.

However, the anime doesn't give any indication of their exact ages, so it's hard to tell what the actual age gap between them is. Is it stated in the light novels how old Rae was at the time of her death, and/or how old Claire is at the time the story starts?